# Grids are visible on displacement map when baked

Tags: uv, displacement, normal-map, multiresolution

I was making model with multires amd when i finished detailing my model.. i baked it using multi res. But when i baked displacement map it has some line and grid are visible to it as you can see in image

[image: see circle]

I searched about it but i don't get any proper solution. Here see this actual mesh its smooth
[image: high res hand]
[image: high res shoulder]

and now see base mesh

[image: its also super smooth]
[image: ..].

Comment: What is the resolution of your displacement map? Is it very big? Also have you tried to use it as is? If you did, do you have any undesired effects?

Comment: Its resolution is 4096 (4k) and when i put that displacement map in material setup it creates that bump same as in map ...help me out with this problem...but as you said resolution is very big i will try to bake it different resolution (1k or 2k)

Comment: Does the same problem appear when you bake normals?

Comment: Yaa it appears again. this time i baked it at 1k result was same!!!

Comment: May be it's something with the mesh then? How heavy is your blend file?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/jCccygFW :- here is the screenshot of my blend file.  It's blender file size is 650mb and BLEND1 file is also 650mb.  Does size matter ??

Comment: It's not a matter of size, I just wanted to know if uploading it was an option so that I could take a look at it but apparently it's a bit too heavy.

Comment: Should i share it with you ??

Comment: I can't download such a heavy file, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apply <kbd>***Base***</kbd> in Multires modifier shape tab
[image: Multires modifier]